# How do set background image to fit screen size without css positioning?

Tags: css, image

How do set background image to fit screen size without css positioning? Im doing school work and I would like to set a background image but my professor said I cannot use positioning so is there another way around it?

Comment: Can you use _background positioning_? That is a weird restriction.

Comment: This has been asked:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Comment: No I can't use anything that includes the word position

Comment: css properties left,right, margin, padding doesnt have word "position" in them..!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
html{
    background:url('backgroundimage.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
}

body{

    min-height:100%;/*hack for some mobile browsers */
    min-width:100%;
}
```

[reference link](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/06/quick-tip-fullscreen-backgrounds/)