# How stretch background image when added large content without repeating image in css

Tags: css, image, dynamic

I want to stretch image when content of html is increase. And whenever content is increases then automatically background image stretch without repeating in css. In Html pages.

Comment: https://github.com/danmillar/jquery-anystretch

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale CSS background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out!](http://jsfiddle.net/mx8rr/)

Here is my CSS:

```
div {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

`background-size: cover;` will also work, with a slightly different effect.

Comment: See also http://jsfiddle.net/zPdQh/ for some javascript which dynamically makes the element grow in size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion to avoid stretching:

```
div {
background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
background-position: 50% 0;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/mx8rr/1/

Comment: One question i have regarding background image, I want When menu text is increases that time background image is stretch i.e width of image should increases with out using repeat y. Because which image is i used that having the bullets on all 4 corners so it look so bad. So you have any solution please give me.. I try lots.. please help me !

Answer (score -1):

We can stretch background image when add large content without repeating image in css

please try next:

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: contain;
```