# Can't get background header image to fit to width.. tried everything

Tags: css, image, background, width, resolution

I've searched for hours upon hours and now I figure it's time for me to ask the question. I can't get my background image that is placed in my header to fit to screen. It works for every kind of computer resolution fine, but where I run into trouble is when I am viewing on a phone, it doesn't want to shrink. I've done min-height, max-height, I've tried everything, the problem partly I think is that the header div itself is smaller than this image, but I also don't really know and need some guidance, i'm relatively new to the CSS scene.

Here is what I have:

```
#header {
    background-image: url('http://hamsoc.polymath.io/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/hamsocheader.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 209px;
}
```

Website url is http://hamsoc.polymath.io

Thank you for your help in advance!

**Duncan Beattie gave me the answer and it worked like a charm. Here is what he said:**

> "You have background-size: cover which is fitting the height of the
>   background image to the fixed height of your div, 209px. remove the
>   fixed height and replace with padding-bottom:15% this will kep the
>   aspect ratio of the div the same and scale the image as viewport gets
>   smaller."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale CSS background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `background-size: cover` which is fitting the height of the background image to the fixed height of your div, 209px.

remove the fixed height and replace with `padding-bottom:15%` this will kep the aspect ratio of the div the same and scale the image as viewport gets smaller.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much! Can you explain how it works? Just so I know for future reference. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Pushing the depth of the container by a percentage of the body width means that it always scales in the same ratio. have a look at [FluidSquares](http://dinosaurswithlaserz.com/2011/07/18/fluid-squares-v2/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the header image in your HTML rather than a background image and then setting a `max-width` like so:

```
#header img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This will also allow you to make the image "clickable" which is generally wanted in a header logo.

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn99X/)

[**FULLSCREEN**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn99X/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the a precentage to set the height of the image in the div?

So set the image height to be say 100% of the div?

If not then maybe you could use some javascript code to detect whether they are on a mobile device, and set the height of it accordingly?

Comment: I have tried to set it to 100% of the div, but the problem the div is so small so I need to define the height in pixels otherwise it won't show the entire image.

Answer (score 0):

The hard coded height value is messing you up. Try playing with the `height: 290px` value and watch the header fit properly on smaller screens.

Instead of a background image, you can try putting the image in the html and using a CSS property to help the content scale down on smaller screens.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```