# Wordpress header image is not responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am still trying to get the hang of responsive web design.

I am not able to get the header images to scale as the browser gets smaller.

This is the site,

http://instreamenergy.com/strategic-partnerships/

if I try to make the .header-image #header #title-area height:100% or anything else it just reverts to 20px or something and is stuck there.

Any tips would be awesome!
thanks

Comment: Are you using media queries, or just % widths?

Comment: I'm using % widths, but also have been tweaking some things with @media for under 480px width screens

Comment: If you set the media query to change the font size below a certain screen width, it should work fine. The header images themselves are constrained by the font sizes. If the fonts get smaller, the navigation will, too.

Comment: thanks, but I am not talking about the navigation bar images. I am talking about the main header banner image. It is 985 x 386px but it does not scale at all. I got the logo image to scale when I make the browser smaller, but those main banner images do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the CSS3 property, `background-size`
since your image is a background image for a DIV.

- [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)
- http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

If you were using an image tag, `<img>` you could do this:

```css
img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

You also need to get rid of some of the cruft in your CSS for `#title-area`. Doesn't look like it needs to be `floated: left;` or have `overflow: hidden;`.  Removed `width`, changed `height` to `min-height`.  `no-repeat` added to `background`.

I would update it to:

```css
#title-area {
     background: url(your-image.jpg) no-repeat;
     padding-left: 0;
     min-height: 386px;
     float: none;
     overflow: visible;
     background-size: 100% auto;
}
```