# Responsive image inside a dynamic block

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I need to code the following block. The main block is responsive, and it has 2 other blocks inside, one of them has a static width, and other is dynamic (the img). How to make an image a fluid width, but the static height inside the main container?

the screenshot is here — http://joxi.ru/9xcvUtg5CbAxZuPPZH4

Comment: Not really clear. Also you should show us what did you try

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LSRPk/

Comment: Thanks, http://jsfiddle.net/LSRPk/ is something similar, bud i should make the image height the same height as the main block height.

Comment: So the image is allowed to be distorted?

Comment: Yes, ideally, it should fit in it's block, without changing the aspect ratio.

Comment: http://playground.obuh.by/tmp just the code, without images, the main gray box is image

Comment: sooo you want 1. to keep aspect ratio 2. fill every pixel on the right 3. cut off invisible parts (above/below the big box)

Comment: yes, is it able to make? for example, to fit image by height in the box, and crop (to make invisible) other patrs of the picture.

Comment: This may be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Comment: the image should be as an <img> tag, not as the background. is it possible?

Comment: Maybe, but I have to go: http://jsfiddle.net/LSRPk/1/

Answer (score 0):

It needs 2 wrapper divs, but it seems to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/LSRPk/2/

The HTML:

```
<div class="bonsai-kitten">
    any<br>content<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>height
    <div class="rubberimage">
      <div class="vertical-centerer">
        <img src="kitten.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bonsai-kitten {
    border: 3px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

/* image area next to the sidebar */
.rubberimage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px; /* assuming fixed sidebar width */
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rubberimage .vertical-centerer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;  right: 0;  /* means width: 100%; */
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 10000px; /* large enough? */
    margin-top:  -5000px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.rubberimage img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```