# How to stretch a background-image with css

Tags: php, html, css, background, html-helper

I tried everything, I used background-position: 100%; etc.

```
        a.textlink:link { color: #8E7086; font: bold 11pt Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 10px; }
        a.textlink:visited { color: #8E7086; font: bold 11pt Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; }
        a.textlink:hover { color: #756C63; font: bold 11pt Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; }
        a.textlink:active { color: #8E7086; font: bold 11pt Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; }
        body { 
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
            background-color: #FFF;
            text-align: center;
                            background-image: url(images/Template/radeberger_wrapper.jpg);
                            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                            background-position: 100%;
```

Comment: here's a good resource: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

The first one will allways cover the whole element, but is css3 (modern browsers only).
The second one will always have the full width, keeping aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You should look this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background?rq=1), It has lot's of discussions on same issue.

```
    background-size: 100% auto;
```

Read here [CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size)