# Resizing a background image to automatically fit multiple screens?

Tags: html, css, background, resize, screen

I'm very new to this but I'm working on a website in HTML/CSS. The background looks fine on my macbook pro, but when I view my site on any larger screen, the background repeats and the site content stays in the top left hand corner instead of moving to the middle of the screen.
Is there any way I can make my site look the same on larger screens as it does on my own? Is there a tag to resize an entire website to fit whatever screen is viewing it?

Thanks

Comment: You should include code in your post, and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem, so we can see more easily what it is you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You should explore [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).  Do a web search for the term "responsive css" and you'll get a plethora of frameworks and tools to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

before you study responsive design, you might want to learn more about CSS in general. a lot of people don't like w3, but they do have an easy to understand (and quick!!) css class tutorial to go through. http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp
responsive design would be step #2 to learn about.... its VERY important thing to keep in mind when you create styling.

also, here is a stackoverflow question that answers your question [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)
....and some more help on css backgrounds http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/02/backgrounds-in-css-everything-you-need-to-know/

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background: url(path/to/your/image) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Try this. It has the background move to the middle of the screen.

It's not easy to scale the background image.
It's not a good idea to scale it, either.