# Stretch image CSS?

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

I got a collection of flag sprites [here](http://flag-sprites.com).

**How it basically works:** 
It has one png file containing all the flags, that's used as a background of a class.
There's a different subclass for every flag, which set's the background position.

```
.flag {
width: 18px;
height: 12px;
background:url('images/flags.png') no-repeat
}

.flag.flag-ao {background-position: -18px 0}
```

Unfortunately it's so small you need a magnifier.
Is there a way to zoom/stretch it?

(I tried `height` and `width` but they just uncover rest of the flags)

Comment: It will become ugly if you make it bigger. It's better to use bigger images.

Comment: `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: you can use transform scale property to you div but it will not support old browser    transform: scale(2,2);
                       -ms-transform: scale(2,2); 
                       -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);

Comment: Besides that, this question has been asked before and you can find it in 1 simple search... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Comment: @abhitalks No, it will uncover the other images.

Comment: @Claudio: would be better to understand if you could share relevant markup and css. better still, make a fiddle if you can.

Comment: Found an attribute `zoom` in CSS3. Not very browser friendly though, as older browser don't support CSS3. @rednaw You were right.

Comment: @abhitalks Sorry, I can't really make a working fiddle for some reason. http://jsfiddle.net/heb6c/ But there's the markup that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this 
But the image will blur due to strech
Check if it work out for you

```
     .flag.flag-ao {background-position: -18px 0; 
        -webkit-transform:scale(3,3);
        -moz-transform:scale(3,3);
        -ms-transform:scale(3,3);
         transform:scale(3,3);
     }
```

[Check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZExkD/)

Comment: Yep, it destroys the quality. It also stacked my two images... `zoom` worked the best for me, but also failed in quality.