# css - how to stretch and auto-resize background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my background image to stretch across the entire page, but so far i have this:

[image]

This is the picture i want stretched across the browser window:

[image]

My external CSS contains the code below:

```
hr {color:sienna;}
p {margin-left:20px;}
body {background-image:url("mybackground.jpg")}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can edit the CSS file to fix my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale CSS background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

However please bear in mind [which browsers this supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). For example, this won't work in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 10):

Another option would also include:

```
body{
   background-image:url("mybackground.jpg")
   background-size:contain;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size: cover`. Note its browser support.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Answer (score 1):

Background size will do the trick:

```
    body { 
     background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
   }
```

Check this out for more info:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this an `<img>` tag, with a low `z-index`, with `position: fixed` and then for the `<img>` tag, use `height: 100%; width: auto` or the opposite.

This method is cross-compatible for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
background-size: 10px 10px
```

Change 10 to the width and height of the body

You can also do

```
background-size: 100%
```

Comment: How do you know the width and height of the body in pixels? 320px, 2560px, absolutely any value in-between that is an integer?

Comment: Use `background-size: 100%`

Comment: _absolutely any value in-between that is an integer?_ @FelipeAls Is this a question?

Comment: A badly worded remark: *it could be* any value between 320 and 2560

Comment: Here's the result with `background-size: 100%`: http://jsfiddle.net/6TT2v/ Fine if by miracle the image has the same ratio W/H as the page, otherwise...

Comment: Looks like the width resizes fine, you arn't going to want to resize the height as well or the ratio will be warped so you would use `background-repeat: no-repeat` ...what's the issue?