# How can I adjust an image to the background of a div?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to do a `header` on my page in which I want to show an image. To do the `header` I use a `div`:

```
<div id = "header">
</div>
```

And I want that an image will be on the background of that `div` so I put on the `CSS`:

```
#header{
    background-image: url('img/cars.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;

    top: 0px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

But it is shown like if the image had been cut. I tried replacing `background-size: 100%;` to `background-size: cover;` but the efect it is the same.

I also tried adding these lines:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

but the result are the same.

If I try to get it with `background-size: contain` the image is being reduced from the right.

What can I do to see the full image on my div?

**P.S:** I have seen this question [css - how to stretch and auto-resize background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209840/css-how-to-stretch-and-auto-resize-background-image) but the answers provided did not change anything in my case.

**EDIT:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/er1v054u/4/) you can see the effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you need my friend is `background-position` for that.

Comment: Better if you could provide a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net), it will be easy to help you out.

Comment: @divy3993 How can I add an external image there?

Comment: edit the question and click on the image icon

Comment: @defcon2 I mean on the demo page that `divy3993` provided to me.

Comment: @divy3993 Question edited.

Comment: Ok what part do you want to view from an image, as whole image can not be viewed with also not getting compressed. Basically you will be using `background-position` and `background-size` for this along with **media-queries** if you need to view perfect in all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code:

```
background-size: 100% 150px;
```

So the width is 100% but the height always remains 150px.

Remember that this will stretch your picture if you don't give a fixed width to the header.

Here a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shbLd8v3/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below if this is what you want,

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#header {
  background-image: url('http://www.disney.es/sites/default/files/styles/retina-reduction/public/Cars/GENERIC/Section%20Listings/ICE/msf_cars_ice_lst_characters.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: 800ms all ease;
  -moz-transition: 800ms all ease;
  -ms-transition: 800ms all ease;
  transition: 800ms all ease;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Try this and you can use  `background-position: 100%;`

Comment: It is also cut and it is repeated a lot of times. I do not want to repeat the image.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat image then use background-size: 100% 150%;