# How to display a gif fullscreen for a webpage background?

Tags: html, css, gif

I'm trying to make a GIF fit my whole screen, but so far its just a small square that is on my screen while the rest is white. However, I want it to take up all the space.

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background ?

Answer (score 47):

if it's background, use `background-size: cover;`

```css
body{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx8MT.gif');
    background-size: cover;
    
    
    
    height: 100vh;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**IMG Method**

If you want the image to be a stand alone element, use this CSS:

```
#selector {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<img src='folder/image.gif' id='selector'/>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcQpv/)**

Please note that the img tag would have to be inside the body tag ONLY.  If it were inside anything else, it may not fill the entire screen based on the other elements properties.  This method will also not work if the page is taller than the image.  It will leave white space.  This is where the background method comes in

**Background Image Method**

If you want it to be the background image of you page, you can use this CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('folder/image.gif');
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5TH/)**

Or the shorthand version:

```
body {
    background:url('folder/image.gif') repeat-y 100% 100% fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc49C/4/)**

Comment: would I img src my gif to add it in?

Comment: @user3264048 See edit.  There are multiple ways to approach this.

Comment: @user3264048 Define "doesn't take the full screen" for me.  I am working on some fiddles right now as demonstrations.

Comment: The gif is on the right side of my screen, like a medium size rectangle.

Comment: @user3264048 Can you please post the rest of your HTML in your question or a fiddle?  I think there is something else affecting your image.

Comment: This **repeats** the image, not stretch-to-fill as the OP may have intended.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a background with your GIF file and set the body this way:

```
body{
background-image:url('http://www.example.com/yourfile.gif');
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Change background image URL with your GIF. With `background-position: center` you can put the image to the center and with `background-size: cover` you set the picture to fit all the screen. You can also set `background-size: contain` if you want to fit the picture at 100% of the screen but without leaving any part of the picture without showing.

Here's more info about the property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Hope it helps :)

Comment: MDN is much more reliable than w3schools.

Comment: Thanks @zsaat14! I didn't know MDN had that reference guide! I'll bookmark it :)

Comment: doesn't take up full screen

Comment: Check if adding `width:100%` and `height:100%` to `body` works

Answer (score 0):

if you're happy using it as a background image and CSS3 then  `background-size: cover;` would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for.

## CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.gif-container {
  background: url("image.gif") center;
  background-size: cover;

  height: 100%;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<div class="gif-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS Style tag put this:

```
body {
  background: url('yourgif.gif') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that it's parent size is 100%