# how to stretch or fit a background image using css attribute background in a class

Tags: html, css

How to stretch or fit a background image using css attribute **background** in a class. I am using a icon in li and want to fit on specific width. but it not render.

HMTL code.

```
<ul>
   <li class="social-bg-facebook">F</li>
   <li class="social-bg-twitter">T</li>
   <li class="social-bg-user">U</li>
   <li>UN</li>
</ul>
```

i am using these classes to fit background in **li**

CSS code.

```
.icon-list li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -36px;
    left: 5px;

}
.icon-list li.social-bg-facebook {
    background:url(images/facebook.png) no-repeat;
    width:35px;
}
.icon-list li.social-bg-twitter {
    background:url(images/twitter-icon.png) no-repeat;
    width:35px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale CSS background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

```
.icon-list li.social-bg-facebook {
    background:url(images/facebook.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width:35px;
}
```

Comment: all is right i got a answer in css background properties 

.icon-list li.social-bg-facebook {
    background:url(images/facebook.png) no-repeat;
    `background-size:cover;`
    `background-size:contain;`
    width:35px;
}
 

`background-size:cover;`
`background-size:contain;`

use one in these