# Div with background-image (100% width 100% height)

Tags: css, image, background

what I want to achieve is a div with a background-image that reflects the size of the div, I do not care who maintain the aspect ratio

### Some test

```
<div style='position:absolute;width:"+obj.width+"px;height:"+obj.height+"px;margin-left:"+obj.left+"px;margin-top:"+obj.top+"px;background-image:url(img.png);background-size: 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;border:1px solid red;'>;
```

[image]

```
<div style='position:absolute;width:"+obj.width+"px;height:"+obj.height+"px;margin-left:"+obj.left+"px;margin-top:"+obj.top+"px;background-image:url(img.png);background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;border:1px solid red;'>;
```

[image]

```
<div style='position:absolute;width:"+obj.width+"px;height:"+obj.height+"px;margin-left:"+obj.left+"px;margin-top:"+obj.top+"px;background-image:url(img.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;border:1px solid red;'>;
```

[image]

Comment: This is a bad question, you could have just used Google. This is basic stuff here.

Comment: Duplicate of [Stretch and scale CSS background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

OR

```
background-size:auto 100%;
```