# Keep same background throughout my website

Tags: html, css

I want to keep a static background for my website same through out all the pages.
Meaning, the background should be same through out the applications . 
I tried doing

```
html {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #f00 url(http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But this assigns background only to selected area in my website.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about applying it to the `body {...}` ? (p.s. - setting the height and width to `300px` might also be part of the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00 url(http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `html` to `body`

```
body
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #f00 url(http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be `body` not `html`

```
body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #f00 url(http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

think about height and width once.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
body{
     background: #f00 url(http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg);
     background-size: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And make sure that all your html pages link to your css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_your_file.css" media="all"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you have assigned `height` and `width` in your `css` class.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: 100% 100%`. And don't use `height` & `width`attributes for `.html` selector. Apply the properties on `.body` selector.
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background/388817#388817) for more knowledge.