# How to make different kind of borders

Tags: html, css, border

I want this kind of border on an div, there is a way to make it?

[image: border type]

I tried putting an image background on a div, but is not functional for responsive purposes:

```css
.center-social-networks {
    background: url("http://cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/linear_rectangle.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-social-networks"></div>
```

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: done I update my post

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale CSS background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a property who makes me set my own border type, I found border-image, with this new css3 property I just can specy a route for an image, this property makes me set my own border type.

example below:

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(http://cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/square1.png) 5 space;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">text inside<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... by setting background-size to 100% 100%

```css
.center-social-networks {
    background: url("http://cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/linear_rectangle.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-social-networks"></div>
```

Comment: this is not functional for me

Comment: @KennyAmaro Not functional how?

Comment: @KennyAmaro the border is taking 100% width and height for me and resizes as I resize the screen

Comment: please check out my answer, that was what I was looking for

Comment: @KennyAmaro well, you were not clear in your question on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: are you sure? "I want this kind of border on an div, there is a way to make it?"

Comment: @KennyAmaro For example in your question you were using the image linear_rectangle.png but in your "answer" you are using a different image. How is that being clear on what you're trying to achieve?