# HTML CSS Background is not covering page

Tags: html, css

When I run my code for my HTML and CSS project, I have a background, which I set in the CSS class. This background is constructed in the HTML file. But it does not seem to cover the entire screen for my computer. When I try to edit the height variable, it doesn't change the height of the background, which leaves me clueless.

```
.gradient{
   width: 100wh;
   height: 90vh;
   color: #fff;
   background: radial-gradient(#EE7752, #CF22E7);
   background-size: 400% 400%;
   -webkit-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
   -moz-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
   animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
}

<div class="jumbotron text-center gradient">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="lead" style="color:#FFFFFF"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **`background-size: cover;`** ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 2):

you can add this one   `background-size: 300px 100px, cover;`

```
.gradient{
width: 100wh;
height: 90vh;
color: #fff;
background: radial-gradient(#EE7752, #CF22E7);
background-size: 300px 100px, cover !important;
-webkit-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
}

<div class="jumbotron text-center gradient">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="lead" style="color:#FFFFFF"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `background-size:cover` to your css instedof `background-size:400% 400%`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gradient{
width: 100wh;
height: 90vh;
color: #fff;
background: radial-gradient(#EE7752, #CF22E7);
background-size: cover;
-webkit-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;
animation: Gradient 10s ease infinite;

}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center gradient">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="lead" style="color:#FFFFFF"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done instead of presenting a block of code. The single line of difference can be hard to spot.

Comment: add background-size:cover to  .gradient class

Comment: Please edit your answer to include it there. Comments can be temporary and are often overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to remove the white space around the edges (e.g. cover the entire screen), it is due to the `div` being contained in the `body` element which by default has a `margin` added by the browser.

Try this:

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.gradient {
    height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(#EE7752, #CF22E7);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
}
</style>

 <div class="jumbotron text-center gradient">
     <div class="content">
         <p class="lead" style="color:#FFFFFF"></p>
     </div>
 </div>
```